# Как добавить кнопку в модальном окне, которая откроет еще одно модальное окно? никак не получается

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"><iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: очевидно, сверстать ещё одно окно (с другим id) и сверстать внутри модального окна ещё одну кнопку, которая и будет открывать второе окно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно поместить еще одну кнопку для нового окна в первое модальное и создавать новое окно динамически через `document.createElement`. В нашем случае `document.createElement('div');`. А далее в функции `onclick` написать что-то подобное (Простите за повтор было лень, но думаю смысл понятен)

```
newModalBtn.onclick = () => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        var newModalWindow = document.createElement('div');

        newModalWindow.innerHTML =
            "<div class=\"modal-content\">\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-header\">\n" +
            "            <span class=\"newModalclose\">&times;</span>\n" +
            "            <h2>Modal Header2</h2>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-body\"><iframe name=\"myiframe\"></iframe>\n" +
            "            <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>\n" +
            "            <p>Some other text...</p>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n" +
            "            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" +
            "        <button id=\"newModalBtn\">newModal</button>\n" +
            "    </div>"

        document.body.appendChild(newModalWindow);
        newModalWindow.style.display = "block";
    }
```